# How to have table span the entire height?

Tags: asp.net, html

I have a html table and I am trying to have it span the entire page height. For some reason I am not able to get this to work. I have set the html, body and table height to be 100%, but the table still does not occupy the entire 100%.

Heres the code. It is very basic because I am just trying to have the table occupy the entire height.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication1.WebForm1" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head runat="server">
        <title></title>
        <style type="text/css">
            body,html {    
                margin:0;    
                padding:0;   
                height:100%;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form id="form1" runat="server">
            <table border="2" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="height:100%; width:100%" >
                <tr>
                    <td>ABCD</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

I tried for couple of hours and I could not get it to work. Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: I fear the only way is to dynamically set the table height using client side script at page load... if CSS way fails let me know and I'll come with something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication1.WebForm1" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head runat="server">
        <title></title>
        <link rel="Stylesheet" href="http://yui.yahooapis.com/3.0.0/build/cssreset/reset-min.css">  
        <style>
            body, html, form, table { height:100%; }
            table { border:2px solid gray; }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>ABCD</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Is the table in a form ? make its height 100% too by using style

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the html height attribute to 100%.

```
<table height="100%">
```

Comment: That does not seem to be working

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the height is relative to the current container, which may not be at 100%. See this article:

http://apptools.com/examples/tableheight.php

Comment: As a follow up, the proper CSS might be like this:


html, body
{
  height: 100%;
}

http://www.dailycoding.com/Posts/howtoset100tableheightinhtml.aspx